# a java.lang.NullPointerException when trying to read data from database with JPA

Tags: tomcat, jpa, persistence

i 'm student and i've a web application which have the jbpm 5 framework embeded on it(this question is not about any jbpm 5 related topic but about JPA and persistance of the jbpm classes on a MySql database).
This web app should run on tomcat 7 configured with the Bitronix transaction manager.
JPA is used to persist the jbpm related classes using 2 persistence-units , here is the persistance.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<persistence version="1.0" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm_1_0.xsd" xmlns:orm="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence">
     <persistence-unit name="org.jbpm.persistence.jpa" transaction-type="JTA">
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
        <jta-data-source>java:comp/env/jdbc/testDS1</jta-data-source>
        <class>org.drools.persistence.info.SessionInfo</class>
        <class>org.jbpm.persistence.processinstance.ProcessInstanceInfo</class>
        <class>org.jbpm.persistence.processinstance.ProcessInstanceEventInfo</class>
        <class>org.drools.persistence.info.WorkItemInfo</class>
        <class>org.jbpm.process.audit.ProcessInstanceLog</class>
        <class>org.jbpm.process.audit.NodeInstanceLog</class>
        <class>org.jbpm.process.audit.VariableInstanceLog</class>       


        <class>org.jbpm.task.Task</class>
        <class>org.jbpm.task.Comment</class>
        <class>org.jbpm.task.Attachment</class>
        <class>org.jbpm.task.I18NText</class>
        <class>org.jbpm.task.SubTasksStrategy</class>
        <class>org.jbpm.task.Deadline</class>
        <class>org.jbpm.task.Escalation</class>
        <class>org.jbpm.task.Reassignment</class>
        <class>org.jbpm.task.Notification</class>
        <class>org.jbpm.task.BooleanExpression</class>
        <class>org.jbpm.task.User</class>
        <class>org.jbpm.task.PeopleAssignments</class>


        <properties>

             <!-- H2 dialect  -->

            <!--<property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect"/>-->

             <!-- Oracle dialect   
               <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.OracleDialect"/> 
              -->
             <!-- mysql dialect --> 

            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect"/>

            <property name="hibernate.connection.autocommit" value="false"/>
            <property name="hibernate.max_fetch_depth" value="3"/>
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false" />
            <property name="hibernate.transaction.manager_lookup_class" value="org.hibernate.transaction.BTMTransactionManagerLookup"/>
        </properties>


    </persistence-unit>
    <persistence-unit name="org.jbpm.task">
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>

        <class>org.jbpm.task.Attachment</class>
        <class>org.jbpm.task.Content</class>
        <class>org.jbpm.task.BooleanExpression</class>
        <class>org.jbpm.task.Comment</class>
        <class>org.jbpm.task.Deadline</class>
        <class>org.jbpm.task.Comment</class>
        <class>org.jbpm.task.Deadline</class>
        <class>org.jbpm.task.Delegation</class>
        <class>org.jbpm.task.Escalation</class>
        <class>org.jbpm.task.Group</class>
        <class>org.jbpm.task.I18NText</class>
        <class>org.jbpm.task.Notification</class>
        <class>org.jbpm.task.EmailNotification</class>
        <class>org.jbpm.task.EmailNotificationHeader</class>
        <class>org.jbpm.task.PeopleAssignments</class>
        <class>org.jbpm.task.Reassignment</class>
        <class>org.jbpm.task.Status</class>
        <class>org.jbpm.task.Task</class>
        <class>org.jbpm.task.TaskData</class>
        <class>org.jbpm.task.SubTasksStrategy</class>
        <class>org.jbpm.task.OnParentAbortAllSubTasksEndStrategy</class>
        <class>org.jbpm.task.OnAllSubTasksEndParentEndStrategy</class>

        <class>org.jbpm.task.User</class>



        <class>org.drools.persistence.info.SessionInfo</class>
        <class>org.jbpm.persistence.processinstance.ProcessInstanceInfo</class>
        <class>org.jbpm.persistence.processinstance.ProcessInstanceEventInfo</class>
        <class>org.drools.persistence.info.WorkItemInfo</class>


        <properties>
             <!-- sample H2 configuration -->
             <!--
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="org.h2.Driver"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:h2:mem:droolsflow" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="root"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="sdfsdf"/> -->


            <!-- Sample Oracle Configuration  

             <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@oraclehost:1521:jbpm5" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="user"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="password"/>
           --> 

             <!-- Sample mysql Configuration --> 


             <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/jbpm5webexpl" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="root"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="sdfsdf"/>


            <property name="hibernate.connection.autocommit" value="false" />
            <property name="hibernate.max_fetch_depth" value="3"/>
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create" />
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

The persistance is working great and i got the database populated with data.So now i want to read from that data particularly from a table named "organizationalentity" which is generated by the persistance work on the database even if this table correspondant 's java class wasn't declared on the persistance.xml(it is weird for me but the table is created and contains data!! but i did it myself when i got the exception but it wasn't the solution). the java class of that table actually exists on a maven referenced jar and not on my packages that i've written myself (this was the reason for which i coudn't add some NamedQueries on it becose this class is a .class and not a .java..)

so i added on my classpath this new OrganizationalEntityDao.java class :

```
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;

import org.jbpm.task.OrganizationalEntity;

public class OrganizationalEntityDao {


    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "org.jbpm.task")
    static EntityManager em;

        public static OrganizationalEntity readById(int id) {
        return em.find(OrganizationalEntity.class,id); 
    }
}
```

And when i run my application i got this error :

```
javax.el.ELException: /index.xhtml @142,119 listener="#{processBean.requestPage}": java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:111)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.core.AjaxBehaviorListenerImpl.processAjaxBehavior(AjaxHandler.java:450)
    at javax.faces.event.AjaxBehaviorEvent.processListener(AjaxBehaviorEvent.java:113)
    at javax.faces.component.behavior.BehaviorBase.broadcast(BehaviorBase.java:106)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.broadcast(UIComponentBase.java:760)
    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:300)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:794)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1259)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:593)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:225)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:927)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1001)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:585)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:1770)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at entities.dao.OrganizationalEntityDao.readById(OrganizationalEntityDao.java:20)
    at entities.beans.ProcessBean.requestPage(ProcessBean.java:121)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:264)
    at org.apache.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:278)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
    ... 27 more
```

i should say that i was wondering the use of JPA for persisting entities (as the EJB work) on tomcat . i didn't use JDBC to do this work as JPA is alreay used.
well guys, any idea ? cheers.

Comment: You won't be able to load an entity if JPA doesn't know about this entity. It should be listed in your persistence.xml as all the other entities. And you rely on CDI dependency injection here, but it seems that you don't have any CDI container available. WHy don't you use the same way to load this entity as for all the other entities you use?

Comment: i ve added <class>org.jbpm.task.OrganizationalEntity</class> in the persistance.xml but it didn't resolve the problem alone and as i have understood from your comment is that the class containing the EntityManager must be managed by CDI or EJB , i thought that it can be done without that. i don't know if tomcat can have a CDI container or not.

Comment: i don't really use these entities myself , it is the jbpm framework who do it internally and i don't know how. thank you anyway.

Comment: You're not forced to use CDI. But the OrganizationalEntityDao code you posted relies on CDI (or another dependency injection framework) to work. Where did you get this DAO code from? Do you understand how it works, and what the annotation it contains does. Why don't you use the same kind of code that you're using everywhere else with success to load this OrganizationalEntity entity from the database?

Comment: Actually OrganizationalEntityDao is a JSF  Managed Bean. This won't do the CDI work of course..

Comment: i picked that code from an application using EJB and this is not possible in tomcat (unless i use the openEjb stuff)

Comment: well, u're right i don't really know that these annotations depend only on a EJB or CDI, i just tried it.

Answer (score 0):

> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
>       at entities.dao.OrganizationalEntityDao.readById(OrganizationalEntityDao.java:20)
>       at entities.beans.ProcessBean.requestPage(ProcessBean.java:121)

Your code is broken. What's on line 20 of OrganizationalEntityDao.java? I suspect you'll find a potential NPE -- the one you are encountering.